# How to use CkEditor in laravel micro framework Lumen

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, lumen

I am trying to implement the ckeditor on my webpage.I am using Laravel micro framework Lumen.i am using ckeditor on my webpage but it not show ckeditor.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="editor">
 <h1>Hello world!</h1>
 <p>I'm an instance of <a href="http://ckeditor.com">CKEditor</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Here is my script files:

```
script src="{{URL::asset('public/admin/assets/layouts/global/scripts/ckeditor.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="{{URL::asset('public/admin/assets/layouts/global/scripts/sample.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My script:

```
  <script>
        initSample();
    </script>
```

How can i get the ckeditor?thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what the function `initSample()` looks like?

Comment: i don't know what is it.! It will there in ckeditor official download file.

Comment: `CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );` replace it with this code and tell me if it works now

Comment: it not show anything..!!

Comment: it's works fine script calling missed here..